# Implementing Custom Authentication Handler for Microsoft Graph SDK

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

My understanding is, I might be wrong, that with Microsoft Graph SDK, you get a **GraphClientFactory** and by using it you can plug in or remove middleware components from the graph client.

Since they provide a way to remove and add middleware, I assumed that we can provide a custom implementation of Authentication Handler as it is basically a delegating handler as can be seen
[here](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet-core/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Graph.Core/Requests/Middleware/AuthenticationHandler.cs).

I have written this code which is very similar to the Original provided by Microsoft Graph but trimmed down just to see if we can actually use custom components/handlers:

```
public class CustomAuthenticationHandler: DelegatingHandler
    {

        internal AuthenticationHandlerOption AuthOption { get; set; }


        public IAuthenticationProvider AuthenticationProvider { get; set; }

        public CustomAuthenticationHandler(IAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider)
        {
            AuthenticationProvider = authenticationProvider;
            AuthOption = new AuthenticationHandlerOption();
        }

        protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage httpRequestMessage, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var authProvider = AuthenticationProvider;

            if (authProvider != null)
            {
                await authProvider.AuthenticateRequestAsync(httpRequestMessage);

                HttpResponseMessage response = await base.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage, cancellationToken);
                
                //do something

                return response;
            }
            else
            {
                return await base.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage, cancellationToken);
            }
        }
    }
```

And this is how I add this handler to pipeline:

```
var handlers = new DelegatingHandler[]
            {
                new CustomAuthenticationHandler(
                    new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(async (requestMessage) =>
                    {

                        var scopes = new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

                        var authResult = await confidentialClientApplication.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes).ExecuteAsync();

                        requestMessage
                            .Headers
                            .Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authResult.AccessToken);

                    })
                ),
                new CompressionHandler(),
                new RetryHandler(),
                new RedirectHandler()
            };
            var client = GraphClientFactory.Create(handlers);
            GraphClient = new GraphServiceClient(client);
```

That's the error message I get when actually sending the request:
**"Code: invalidRequest\r\nMessage: Authentication provider is required before sending a request.\r\n"**

So far I haven't been able to work. My question is this possible or not? Does Microsoft Graph SDK intend to provide this functionality or I understand it completely wrong? If it is possible to add custom handlers, then what am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you please provide the correlation id and timestamp

Comment: Are you still looking any help on this question